# PHP Exploding first part of a string into array elements and the second part into one element

Tags: php

I have a string which gets exploded into an array using the space as a delimiter. Is it possible to , for example explode the first 4 words into the array and the rest into ONE array element?

as of now the code is like this

```
$string = 'This is a string that needs to be split into elements';
$splitarray = explode(' ',$string);
```

This gives an array

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => This
        [1] => is
        [2] => a
        [3] => string
        [4] => that
        [5] => needs
        [6] => to
        [7] => be
        [8] => split
        [9] => into
        [10] => elements

    )
```

What i need is for the array to look like this

```
Array
    (
        [0] => This
        [1] => is
        [2] => a
        [3] => string
        [4] => that
        [5] => needs
        [6] => to be split into elements

    )
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Read the manual, [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) has a third option: `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, **int $limit** ] )` :)

Comment: of course the limit! Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `limit` parameter here.

From **[`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)** documentation:

> If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.

Code:

```
$string = 'This is a string that needs to be split into elements';
$splitarray = explode(' ',$string, 7);
print_r($splitarray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This
    [1] => is
    [2] => a
    [3] => string
    [4] => that
    [5] => needs
    [6] => to be split into elements
)
```

Comment: Yes. Cant believe I overlooked something so simple.